# What To Do With Blueberry Hot Sauce

Tags: sauce, culinary-uses, blueberries, spicy-hot

I bought some blueberry hot sauce while on vacation in Maine. It seemed like a good idea at the time, but now I have no clue what to pair it with. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your question! Please note that questions calling for a list of answers (as opposed to seeking a single "right" answer) should be started as Community Wiki. I've converted the question for you.

Answer (score 2):

I bet it would be delicious with beef. Beef and berries are great together.

Other ideas I just thought of -- use it like you would use jalapeno jelly -- to top baked brie or in a sandwich or spread with cream cheese.

Answer (score 2):

I generally see this kind of sweet pairing with game, like venison. This coming from the vegetarian, but I can't really think of anything vegetarian I would do with it. (Or give it as a gift :).

Comment: I agree.  Any of the game meats would go well with blueberries.  Try wild boar chops if you want something showy on the plate.

Answer (score 1):

BBQ Grilled Peaches: halve and pit peaches, brush with BBQ sauce and grill. Either use your Blueberry Hot Sauce in the BBQ sauce or brush on after grilling. Top with some fresh blueberries and chopped basil.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken would be good in any form with this... shrimp/mussels sound like they would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

What about some of the sweet/spicy applications that seem to be gaining a lot of ground lately.  Try it as a sauce for ice cream, drizzle it over a cheesecake (or bake it into your cheesecake), fill vanilla cupcakes with it; let your blueberry dessert ideas go wild here!